# Setting up OpenGL glut library on Code::Blocks IDE in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, opengl, code-blocks

I am trying to set up OpenGL glut library on Code::Blocks 16.01 IDE in Ubuntu 18.04.2. I have followed [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17291.0) link but when I try to open a freeglut project, I get this error -

> Failed to load the wizard's script. Please check the debug log for details

How to setup OpenGL glut or freeglut library in Ubuntu Code::Blocks correctly?

Comment: What steps did you do, exactly? it sounds like you may have copied the `/usr/share/codeblocks/templates/wizard/glut` to the wrong directory

Comment: I followed the link's steps.